# Android studio in fullScreen

Tags: android, android-studio, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

Is it possible to use **Android Studio in full Screen** for example only that field where we code should show on the whole screen.

like this : [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "distraction free mode":

[image: Distraction Free Mode Screen Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy. Just double click your class.

[image]

Comment: well thank you. I knew that but I'm not talking about that.
I don't want any thing on window except that coding field.

Comment: @Pre_hacker Are you on mac or windows?